# Put a text editor into a Visual Studio Pane?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I know there is a clipboard cycle in Visual Studio, but I need a "longer" lasting clipboard for code-parts I cut from one file and paste it into another part days later.

I just could use another text-file in the project and paste it there, but I would prefer to have a texteditor on one of the always visible panels (like in the properties-pane) where I can copy/paste code snippets.

Is there a way to put a textfile into a pane in VS2012 or is there a plugin for that?

[image: the way I want it]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Toolbox is the place to add code snippets.

Just drag your code to the Toolbox.
[image]

The snippets are added to the `General` tab in the  toolbox.

[image]

You can organize the snippets by adding other tabs (right click the toolbox) and you can rename the snippets in the same way.

To use the code, snippet, drag it to the code window.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. Did not expect to be that easy :)